# Composition adapter implementation java

Tags: java, adapter

I have an external library:

```
public class ExternalLib { ... }
```

I want to use it in my project so I initiated it like this in the class I will use in my project:

```
public class Codec {

    private static final ExternalLib externalLib = new ExternalLib();

    public static String encode(String x, int l, Long s, int f) {
        return externalLib.encode(x, l, s, f);
    }

    public static ExternalLib decode(String y) {
        return externalLib.decode(y);
    }
```

I would like to protect my class Codec in case anyone change sth in class ExternalLib, so was wondering how could I introduce here a new class/interface? and map the externalLib (in the body of decode method)? Was thinking about wrapping externalLib and than mapping it into new object that I will return when performing decode method. Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Why are you wrapping all of that instead of just calling the methods on the external library directly?

Comment: Declare your interface, and create wrapper that will implement that interface using external lib. I think its a facade.